# Changing IN to JOIN inside UPDATE Statement Subquery

Tags: mysql

I have this query, which would work great (I think) with a higher version of MySQL, but unfortunately that's not an option.

I have a database of lottery tickets with the user's email address in each one. I need to find the winners of this lottery, but each email address can have only 1 winning ticket, even if they have multiple winning tickets. I am trying to use multiple subqueries to accomplish this.

I only want to set `winner`='Y' for the highest number of matches per email, so a user can only have 1 "winner" each week.

I want to update 1 row for each email, not 1 row in the entire table.

My objective is to perform all this within a single query, or at the very least reduce the stress on my server as much as possible. I have over 30,000 rows/tickets to process each week.

I'm assuming the best thing to do is to use JOIN instead of IN but I can't figure this out.

```
UPDATE `tickets`
SET `winner`='Y'
WHERE `ticketid` IN
    (SELECT `ticketid`
     FROM `tickets`
     WHERE `email` IN
         (SELECT distinct(email)
          FROM `tickets`
          WHERE `date` BETWEEN '$weekstart' AND '$weekend'
            AND `matches`>='3')
     ORDER BY `matches` DESC LIMIT 1)
```

This query gives me the error: "#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"

Comment: Watch out, i don't think you know what you're doing ! You should first explain what you want to do because this is not clear. Tell us what's your objectives, show us what you've done, the result you have and the result you want

Comment: Updating question now.

Comment: Still not clear what you want to achieve. Update 1 row per email? Or only 1 row in the whole table?

Comment: Yes, only update highest matches per email, so a user can only have 1 "winner" each week. Updating question.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the *`LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery`* restriction, self joining a table is not possible - without some tricks - in the `WHERE` clause of an `UPDATE` statement, not even in the latest MySQL version.

It's usually better to rewrite using joins - although far from trivial:

```
UPDATE 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT email
      FROM tickets
    ) AS e
  JOIN 
    tickets AS t
      ON  t.ticket_id = 
          ( SELECT ti.ticket_id
            FROM tickets AS ti
            WHERE ti.email = e.email
              AND ti.date BETWEEN '$weekstart' AND '$weekend' 
              AND ti.matches >= 3
            ORDER BY ti.matches DESC
            LIMIT 1
          ) 
SET 
    t.winner = 'Y' ;
```

This finds only one `ticket_id` for every distinct value of `emails` in the table (and only if there is a row with the added conditions, date in the wanted week and 3 or more "matches") and then updates.

**Edit**: I was wrong, the above does **not** work, raises the error:

> "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'e' for update in FROM clause"

---

But this (even more convoluted) does work:

```
UPDATE 
    tickets AS u
  JOIN
    ( SELECT t.ticket_id
      FROM
          ( SELECT DISTINCT email
            FROM tickets
          ) AS e
        JOIN 
          tickets AS t
            ON  t.ticket_id = 
                ( SELECT ti.ticket_id
                  FROM tickets AS ti
                  WHERE ti.email = e.email
                    AND ti.date BETWEEN '$weekstart' AND '$weekend' 
                    AND ti.matches >= 3
                  ORDER BY ti.matches DESC
                  LIMIT 1
                ) 
    ) AS x
      ON  x.ticket_id = u.ticket_id
SET 
    u.winner = 'Y' ;
```

Regarding efficiency, I think an index on `(email, date, matches, ticket_id)` would improve it a lot.

If the percent of rows in the table that have `matches >= 3` is small, an alternative index would be on `(email, matches, date, ticket_id)`.

Comment: Yes, thank you I think this is what I'm looking for. I'm getting an error, though. "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'e' for update in FROM clause" any ideas? I'm not experienced with JOINs.

Comment: This works, ypercube! Thank you! I really appreciate your help! The only issue is this times out since I'm running it on a database with over 30000 rows for the specified week, and over 200000 rows in the entire table. Any ideas on how to speed it up? Or should I post another question?

Comment: It's not easy to make this super fast. If the number of different emails in the table is not huge, the index I suggest will be good.

Comment: Can you estimate the percent of rows in the table that have `matches >= 3` and the percent of rows (independent) that are in one week? Added one more option for indexing.

Comment: Using last week as an example, which is a typical week, there were 330 rows with matches >= 3, with ~33000 rows total. During that same week there were 1800 distinct emails in the table. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update one of the rows in tickets where the email has the maximum number of matches -- according to your conditions.

I think this is the query you want:

```
UPDATE `tickets` t JOIN
       (SELECT `email`, max(matches) as maxm
        FROM tickets t
        WHERE `date` BETWEEN '$weekstart' AND '$weekend' AND `matches` >= 3
        GROUP BY email
        ORDER BY maxm DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) te
       ON t.email = t3.email
    SET t `winner` = 'Y'
    LIMIT 1;
```

You might want to put some sort of randomization in, using this `order by`:

```
order by maxm DESC, rand()
```

Comment: YES! This is very smart I didn't think of the max() function. I will work with this but currently it is giving "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`winner`='Y' LIMIT 1' at line 10"

Comment: Hmmm looking into this further I'm finding I may not have explained things well enough. I want update one of the rows in tickets for EACH email that has the maximum number of matches for that email. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
UPDATE tickets
INNER JOIN (
SELECT `ticketid`
FROM `tickets` 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '$weekstart' 
  AND '$weekend' AND `matches`>='3'
ORDER BY `matches` DESC LIMIT 1) t
ON tickets.ticketid = t.ticketid
SET `winner`='Y'
```

Comment: I think LIMIT 1 might be in wrong area. I'll work with this but it is currently only affecting 1 row at a time. edit: This only worked 1 time to update 1 row, and now it is affecting 0 rows.

Comment: So why did you use that?? :-)